# Failed to read artifact descriptor - Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cxf

I have a dependency for Apache's CXF within my pom.xml file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, when I run my pom.xml file, I get the following error message:
"Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.cxf...". I'm using Eclipse, and I see the `cxf` jar is included in my project, but when I right click on `Maven Dependencies` -> `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path`, I see the CXF jar listed as missing.

I've tried right clicking on my project, then going to `Maven` -> `Update Project` -> `Force to Update Snapshot/Release`, but that didn't work. I continued to get the same error.

I then went into the .m2 folder, deleted its contents, and tried the above steps again (Update Project), but now I get an error on all of my jars, and going to `Configure Build Path` again after deleting the .m2 contents, I see **all** of the jars in my project show `Missing` even though I see them in my Solution Explorer, and I see all the required folders in the .m2 folder.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running a maven install: Select your project (preferable parent you it have one), right click, Run as -> Maven Install

Comment: This error is generated when running as Maven Install specifically.

Comment: Then delete in your local repository this artifact so Maven can download it again (I'm thinking that you are connected to the internet).